# React DropdownMultiselect component not updating with new options

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import DropdownMultiselect from "react-multiselect-dropdown-bootstrap";

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(['test'])

  const fetchApi = () => {
    fetch("../api/" + ticket)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      let names = [];
      for(var entry in json){
        names.push(json[entry].print_name);
      }
      setData(names);
    })
  }

  useEffect( () => {
    fetchApi();},
    [])

  console.log('I ran')

  return (
    <div>
      <button> {data[0]} </button>
      <DropdownMultiselect options={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the code above, the button updates with the name that was fetched via the fetch call, but the DropdownMultiSelect does not update its options. Am I doing it wrong, or is there something strange about the DropdownMultiSelect component that is somehow breaking things?

edit: brought the names declaration and the setData call into the second .then statement, still no joy.

Comment: use `setData(names)` inside the 2nd `then` of promise

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't appear to help, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Move the `names` array initialization as well

Comment: Just tried that as well. No change. I think the structure is sound, since the button updates, but I'm missing something where the Dropdown component does not.

Comment: It is issue with the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e7tywo?file=src%2FApp.jsx). Looks like the problem lies within `react-multiselect-dropdown-bootstrap` itself and not your code.

I would suggest using a different library instead like [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select). In general it's always wiser to use third-party libraries which are being maintained frequently and have many weekly downloads.

If yet you still want to stick with `react-multiselect-dropdown-bootstrap` I would suggest creating an [issue](https://github.com/kfrancikowski/react-multiselect-dropdown-bootstrap/issues) on their github repository.

Comment: Phew, okay, so I'm not crazy then. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `react-multiselect-dropdown-bootstrap`v1.0.4

Higher versions have some issues with the data population.

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-curran-zryxj?file=/src/App.js

[image]